# No code for totalMemory() Method in Runtime Class

Tags: java, android, runtime

Here Is Screenshot of official documentation of runtime class:

[image: screenshot]

I know it is implemented with native keyword. So how can I get the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Native methods mean that they're not implemented in Java, but in some other language (like C). In this case, it can be found [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/jni/android_util_Process.cpp#492).

Comment: can you explain me that code? i am not getting that code. i am student in college? so i am not able to understand it now?

Comment: It's using native information available through the unix kernel to get information about the memory ([/proc/meminfo](https://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/5.1/Deployment_Guide/s2-proc-meminfo.html))